# Proof that if polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a rational root $a/b$ and $k$ is an integer, then $a-kb|f(k)$.

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, roots

I'm currently learning about rings and polynomials and I was asked to prove that thing in the title.

So far I can prove that $f(x)$ can be written as $\sum_{i=0}^{n} z_i (x-k)^i$ with $z_0 ,...,z_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ by applying the division algorithm. Consequently $0=f(a/b)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} z_i (\frac{a}{b}-k)^i = \sum_{i=0}^{n} z_i \frac{(a-kb)^i}{b^i} = z_0 +(\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i \frac{(a-kb)^{i-1}}{b^i})(a-kb)$ being $f(k)=z_0$. What I'm unable to prove is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i \frac{(a-kb)^{i-1}}{b^i} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiply what you have found by $b^n$. You get that $a-bk$ divide $b^nf(k)$. Now it remain to show that $a-bk$ and $b^n$ are relatively prime. Note that you may suppose that $a$ and $b$ have no commun divisor.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer.